# Joomla index.php page is automatically redirected with "not found" error

Tags: joomla

I am trying to copy a joomla website to a sub domain of a website: http://sub.domain.com. Database and everything seems fine. When I access http://sub.domain.com, the website is automatically redirected to: http://sub.domain.com/en/index.php and the error is:

```
The page cannot be found

The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Please try the following:

Make sure that the Web site address displayed in the address bar of your browser is spelled and formatted correctly.
If you reached this page by clicking a link, contact the Web site administrator to alert them that the link is incorrectly formatted.
Click the Back button to try another link.
HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

Technical Information (for support personnel)

Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search for the words HTTP and 404.
Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled Web Site Setup, Common Administrative Tasks, and About Custom Error Messages.
```

Yes, I deploy the joomla site on an IIS server but I am sure it is running both for php as well as asp.net.

Any idea about this auto-redirection and how can I solve this?

Comment: Is it Joomla 2.5? every language needs to have a home, that may be the problem...

Comment: @jackJoe I followed this http://internetteachings.com/check-current-joomla-version/ to check my joomla version but there is no version.php inside joomla?

Comment: two questions: did it work before you moved it to the sub-domain? and can you login to the administrator? (http://sub.domain.com/administrator) My guess is that files are missing...

Comment: Hi @jackJoe sub.domain.com/Administrator/index.php works. Off course there is no en/index.php but I think it has something to do with redirection rules that I am not familiar with

Comment: I meant if it (the site without the 404 error) worked before moving to the sub-domain? By entering into the admin part of the site, you can see Joomla's version, which one is it?

Comment: yes, the site originally: http://domain.com works fine. Joomla's version is: Joomla! 2.5.4

Comment: @jackJoe any idea about this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a different server than the one on the main domain? I'm asking this, because the previous server could be an Apache and joomla could be using the .htaccess, and in the IIS that will be ignored. If the server is the same, than I assume the settings on the sub-domain are diferent compared to the main domain, you need to check that.

Comment: yes, it is on different server. the one I am running on IIS and the other is on Linux.

Comment: IT is strange for my site that if I tick on "yes" for: "Remove URL Language Code" the links are broken. any ideas?

Comment: @olidev Have you renamed the web.config file and configured IIS to use it? That's how redirects work on IIS, you probably have a .htaccess file which is being rendered useless

Comment: @udjamaflip so in IIS, I need to use: web.config and .htaccess or web.config.txt and .htaccess.txt?

Comment: You need to either turn off URL rewritting (see my answer) or if you plan to use the rewriting, in IIS, use the web.config (remove the .txt extension). In IIS the .htaccess doesn't work.

Comment: @olidev You need to not use .htaccess, only use web.config as jackJoe has said. To give you a bit more understanding (as you said you're not familiar with these technologies): These 2 files are used by the 2 web servers Apache (.htaccess) and IIS (web.config) in order to interpret inbound URLs which aren't pointing to a file or directory that actually exist. If you have already renamed web.config.txt to web.config and it's still not working I'd suggest going to the admin panel of Joomla I would advise following jackJoe's response to disable url rewriting while we help you debug further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading all your comments, I can give this suggestion:

Knowing that the previous server wasn't an IIS, and when you said it was in a Linux, probably it was an Apache server, then follow these steps:

1. Enter the administration area by going to http://sub.domain.com/administrator/
2. Select "Global Configuration", and select the "Site" tab;
3. Go to the right column and in the "Use URL rewriting" select "no".

If you don't have more than one language, you can do the following (in this example, the English language will be the default):

1. (in the administration area) Go to the menu "Extensions" and select "Language Manager", go to the "Installed - Site" tab;
2. Select (click in the checkbox) the english language and click "Default" (this assumes that there are more than one language in this screen).
3. Go to the menu "Extensions" and select "Plug-in Manager";
4. Select "System - Language Filter", and disable it.

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was to TURN OFF Search engine friendly URL's.

After installing Joomla it was turned on. I already tried the above options. no result.

When hovering my mouse over the second menubutton I did not see the the php code to that article in the left lower corner of my browser but just   mywebsite/folder1/folder2/

and not something like :  index.php?options=com  and so on.....

So I tried to switch OFF the Search engine friendly URL's after I already had the articles, categories and menu's.  And it worked.